# how to access this element

Tags: ruby, xpath, watir

I am using Watir to write some tests for a web application. I need to get the text 'Bishop' from the HTML below but can't figure out how to do it.

```
<div id="dnn_ctr353_Main_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl07_Field_048b9dfa-bc64-42e4-8bd5-b45385e5f45b_view" style="display: block;">
   <div class="workprolabel wpFieldLabel">
    <span title="Please select a courtesy title from the list.">Title</span>&nbsp;<span class="validationIndicator wpValidationText"></span>
   </div>
   <span class="wpFieldViewContent" id="dnn_ctr353_Main_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl07_Field_048b9dfa-bc64-42e4-8bd5-b45385e5f45b_view_value"><p class="wpFieldValue ">Bishop</p></span>
  </div>
```

Firebug tells me the xpath is:

```
html/body/form/div[5]/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/span/span/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/span[1]/div[2]/span/p/text()
```

but I cant format the element_by_xpath to pick it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the paragraph right away if it's unique:

```
my_p = browser.p(:class, "wpFieldValue ")
my_text = my_p.text
```

See [HTML Elements Supported by Watir](https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/HTML-Elements-Supported-by-Watir)

Comment: Try to access the paragraph first using xpath.
Then use .html method to see what's inside the paragraph. Maybe you navigate to a wrong paragraph.

Comment: not sure what you mean here. when i tried the code above i just got unable to locate element by class "wpFieldValue".

Comment: Try without xpath as shown below and see if you still cannot access the paragraph:

    my_span = browser.span(:id, "dnn_ctr353_Main_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl07_Field_048b9dfa-bc64-42e4-8bd5-b45385e5f45b_view_value")

    my_p = my_span.p(:class, "wpFieldValue ")

    puts my_p.text

Comment: genius - that worked. also it needed the space off the end like you said. thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//span[@id='dnn_ctr353_Main_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl07_Field_048b9dfa-bc64-42e4-8bd5b45385e5f45b_view_value']//text()
```

EDIT:

Maybe this will work

```
path = "//span[@id='dnn_ctr353_Main_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl07_Field_048b9dfa-bc64-42e4-8bd5b45385e5f45b_view_value']/p";
ie.element_by_xpath(path).text
```

And check if the span's id is constant

Comment: thanks for the answer, i've tried it but it doesnt seem to return the text:

bleh = @@ie.element_by_xpath("//span[@id='dnn_ctr353_Main_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl07_Field_048b9dfa-bc64-42e4-8bd5b45385e5f45b_view_value']/p/text()")
    
puts bleh

this just returns whitespace

Comment: tried it with setting the path but got this error:
NoMethodError: undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass.
it just seems to not want to pick up the element. there must surely be a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an extra space in the end of the name?

```
<p class="wpFieldValue ">
```

Comment: the space is there in the html so i dont think that should matter?

Comment: taking the space off worked like you suggested. this seems a bit strange to me since the space is in the html, but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these (worked for me, please notice trailing space after `wpFieldValue` in the first example):

```
browser.p(:class => "wpFieldValue ").text
#=> "Bishop"

browser.span(:id => "dnn_ctr353_Main_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl07_Field_048b9dfa-bc64-42e4-8bd5-b45385e5f45b_view_value").text
#=> "Bishop"
```

Comment: thanks - i managed to get it working by doing what katmoon suggested. weirdly i had to take the trailing space out for it to work

Answer (score 0):

It seems in run time THE DIV style changing NONE to BLOCK.

So in this case we need to collect the text (Entire source or DIV Source) and will collect the value from the text

**For Example :**

```
text=ie.text

particular_div=text.scan(%r{div id="dnn_ctr353_Main_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl07_Field_048b9dfa-bc64-42e4-8bd5-b45385e5f45b_view" style="display: block;(.*)</span></div>}im).flatten.to_s

particular_div.scan(%r{ <p class="wpFieldValue ">(.*)</p> }im).flatten.to_s
```

The above code is the sample one will solve your problem.